# Team Explorer Everywhere CLC mapping error: "First free argument must be a server path"

Tags: shell, command-line, tfs, team-explorer-everywhere

I am trying to create a working folder mapping from a server path and local path.

**Create Workspace**

```
./tf workspace -new -collection:http://tfs.wtqa.int.thomson.com:8080/tfs//WTQA -login:usrName@domain,password WORKSPACE_SCM_32
```

Workspace successfully created.

**Map Workspace**

```
./tf workfold -map -workspace:WORKSPACE_SCM_32 -login:userName@doamin,password "$/POC-MSFAgile6.2Project/POC Source Code" /blackduck/project/Protex_SCM_Test_32
```

but it says "An argument error occurred: First free argument must be a server path"

Comment: Surprising.  If you use single quotes around your server path instead of double quotes (eg `'$/POC...'`), do you still have this problem?

Comment: Could be that the shell is interpreting the $ symbol?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. What solved to me was using single quotes instead of double quotes:

```
./tf workfold -map -workspace:WORKSPACE_SCM_32 -login:userName@doamin,password '$/POC-MSFAgile6.2Project/POC Source Code' '/blackduck/project/Protex_SCM_Test_32'
```